# Vim syntax highlight two specific words with a space (regex)

Tags: regex, vim

I have created this file called *"~/.vim/syntax/proc.vim"* and have been populating regex expressions (I think that's what they call it). I'm having to write some test scripts in this test language developed back in the 90's called STOL for a spacecraft payload. I'm working in a secured environment so the only thing I have access to is vim.

STOL lets you write several different types of print statements and I would like some syntax highlighting difference between each type of message (error message, info message, etc).

My vim color profile called *"~/.vim/color/molokai.vim"* lets me link various regex expressions to a specific syntax class which will invoke a specific color. For example, to highlight keywords I specify two lines like...

```
" This is the regex where two keywords have been defined
syntax keyword procKeywords IF ELSE

" This is how I link the above regex to a molokai color class
" which is called Keyword
highlight link procKeywords Keyword
```

I would essentially like to do the same for some error and info messages that STOL defines like the following...

```
EVENT ERROR "This is a error message"
EVENT INFO "This is a info message"
```

How can I match on two specific words with a space between them? I need something like the following in my *"~/.vim/syntax/proc.vim"*. The following is wrong but I'm just writing it out showing you what I'm thinking...

```
syntax match procInfo "EVENT INFO"
syntax match procError "EVENT ERROR"
highlight link procInfo ModeMsg
highlight link procError ErrorMsg
```

Comment: I tried your last four lines and they work as-is (assuming you haven't defined `EVENT` as a keyword separately).

Comment: that's hilarious. I've tried many ways and then decided to write this post. I literally had no idea that the way I wrote it above (just to be helpful and descriptive) would ACTUALLY WORK. Thanks melpomeme

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt already mostly works. However, `:syntax match` does not automatically enforce whole-keyword match like `:syntax keyword`, so you'd get false highlighting on e.g. `MYEVENT INFORMATION`, too. You can easily fix that by adding the keyword boundary atoms [`:help /\<`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3C) to the regular expressions:

```
syntax match procInfo "\<EVENT INFO\>"
syntax match procError "\<EVENT ERROR\>"
```